# force macro evaluation in C

Tags: c, string, macros, c-preprocessor

I want to change an extensively used C macro that today takes a string as argument to just take the name of the string without quotation marks. I will then stringify the name in the macro using #. I want the change to be easy to adapt to for the user (removal of the quotation marks in the easiest case).

Macro example, change from:

```
#define MY_MACRO(x) (foo(x))
```

to

```
#define MY_MACRO_NEW(x) (foo(#x))
```

The problem is that sometimes a macro is used as argument instead of a string directly, like this:

```
#define BAR "bar"
MY_MACRO(BAR);
```

if the quotation marks are removed and the macro is changed:

```
#define BAR bar
MY_MACRO_NEW(BAR);
```

BAR will not be evaluated since MY_MACRO_NEW stringify using #, the resulting string will therefore be BAR rather than the desired bar.

Is this a way to force evaluation of BAR before it is being evaluated by MY_MACRO_NEW? Something like:

```
#define BAR bar
MY_MACRO_NEW(MACRO_EVAL(BAR));
```

Thanks!

Comment: Always good to read [the manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.4.3/cpp/Stringification.html) (that's the gcc manual so adjust to taste). That very thing is explained there: *If you want to stringify the result of expansion of a macro argument, you have to use two levels of macros.* That's followed by a concrete example. Is that acceptable for your use case?

Comment: ```#define MY_MACRO_NEW(x) MY_MACRO_NEW_(x)``` and ```#define MY_MACRO_NEW_(x) (foo(#x))``` solve your problem?

Comment: Thanks Matheus, exactly what I wanted!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a macro that does nothing to pass a cycle.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define MY_MACRO_NEW(x) MY_MACRO_NEW_(x)
#define MY_MACRO_NEW_(x) (foo(#x))

void foo(const char *msg) {
    printf("%s\n", msg);
}

#define BAR bar

int main() {
    MY_MACRO_NEW(BAR);
    return 0;
}
```

Outputs:

```
bar
```

If your evaluation takes more than one expansion cycle you will need more dummy macros.